# Bus Error just by launching the haxe commando in OSX Terminal

Tags: macos, haxe

I wanted to do again to develop in haxe on my MacBook after quite a long time. So I go on haxe.org, download the mac installer and install the latest version of haxe with it.

Then I open the terminal and type `haxe`, just to encounter this short error message:

```
Bus Error
```

Well, did I do something wrong? I'm using OSX 10.4, can it be that the latest version of haxe is not supported on this operating system?

**UPDATE:**

Looking into the system log, I found out that after the installer was called, the following messages:

```
Nov 12 18:12:16 my-computer authexec: executing /Volumes/haXe Installer/haXe Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/hxinst-osx
Setting FD_CLOEXEC on all file descriptors
Initializing child but not closing any file descriptors...
Initializing child but not closing any file descriptors...
Nov 12 18:13:25 my-computer crashdump[1655]: haxe crashed
Nov 12 18:13:25 my-computer crashdump[1655]: crash report written to: /Users/myuser/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/haxe.crash.log
```

Also, investigating the crash log, I got a name for the exception which resulted from the crash:

```
Exception:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (0x0001)
Codes:      KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE (0x0002) at 0x00000000
```

Any idea? I'm investigating the problem further.

Comment: What does "Haxe commando" refer to in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Bus error means that the program itself is broken (specifically, it means that the program used an unaligned or completely garbage pointer). To find out why, you could try attaching gdb (gdb haxe) and poking around

Comment: I would like to do that... just I have no idea where to begin. To tell the truth, I never heard of gdb before.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the installer was built on and targeted for a later version of OS X (either 10.5 or 10.6).  You may find more information in your system log (/Applications/Utilities/Console.app). You could ask in the [Haxe community](http://haxe.org/com) or, if you're feeling brave, you could try [building your own version from source](http://haxe.org/doc/build/haxe_macosx_build).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there were such an useful utility (to show that I am mainly working on windows those days...), and it gave me some kind of useful information, I'm editing the question with it.